# C encapsulation using const pointers to const data

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question about encapsulating my modules (a .c/.h file pair) in C.

People typically use access functions like getTime(char * time) or so on to access internal variables of a module without providing the ability to mess with them.

Right now, I'm using constant pointers to constant data, pointed at internal structues to do the same thing. I think this works well becuase other modules can look at the data in a structure without being able to alter it, and it saves the overhead of a function call. (this is for embedded stuff, so a function call is 'expensive-ish').

I'd just like some opinions on whether this is valid encapsulation, etc. I suppose they could set a pointer to it that isnt constant then they could mess with the data?
An example:
blah.h

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char data;
    unsigned int intdata;
} myStruct;

extern const myStruct * const ptrConstMyStruct;
```

blah.c

```
static myStruct thisIsMyModulesData;
const myStruct * const ptrConstMyStruct = &thisIsMyModulesData;
```

anotherFile.c

```
variable = ptrConstMyStruct->data;
ptrConstMyStruct->data = variable; //compile error!
```

Comment: Do you really need pointers here?

Comment: I guess that's the best you can do. In C++ too, we have the const_cast that can cast away the constness, but we all live with it.But there's a limitation. you cannot prevent modifications tomembers of 'data' if it is a structure e.g. something like ptrConstMyStruct->data->foo = variable.

Comment: So do you think it is only 'correct' encapsulation to only access data in a module through function calls, where if you need a structure, you pass a structure in and the module copies its own data in so you can't even get at the original? I think I'm answering my own question the more I think about it.

Comment: @vrk001: `const_cast` in C++ doesn't do what you think. You're probably thinking about something that's UB.

Comment: I always thought UB meant Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Using incomplete types and just forward declaring the struct in the header file is the preferred way.

Constness, in terms of encapsulation, is more a way to declare that a particular function won't mutate the given object. In your solution you would have to cast away the constness which seems to be counter intuitive. Or do you not use the const pointer as arguments to mutating functions ever?

Furthermore, encapsulation is about hiding implementation and detail, which cannot be done if you expose the structures that *are the implementation*.

Edit to explain forward declarations:

MyCode.h:

```
struct my_struct;
```

MyCode.c:

```
struct my_struct { .... };
```

The above means users of MyCode will be able to use pointers to my_struct but not inspect its members.

Comment: What would it look like? I'm not sure how to forward declare a typedef struct.

Comment: I think I'm using the term encapsulation to mean data protection, which is wrong on my part, sorry :)

Comment: @Revenant Search Stack Overflow and the web for "opaque type", I think it is the most common term used for this. (_Incomplete type_ is a concept in the C standard that applies to a lot of other variable kinds too, and not just structs.)

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulation allows you to change the internal mechanism, and prevents users from changing your internal data. One way to do this is with getter and setter functions, which would both encapsulate and allow you to do your const thing.

Comment: I think what you're describing is the common way. It just isn't as efficient.

Comment: True, that's the tradeoff. In most cases, maintainable code trumps efficiency. Are you doing this in a time-critical inner loop?

Comment: @Revenant It _is_ just as efficient. Such functions are normally inlined by the compiler's optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some statements in your question that might suggest of the true source of the problem.

> I think this works well becuase other modules can look at the data...

If other modules can look at the data, it is not encapsulated. If other modules *need* to look at the (raw) data, then why are you trying to make it private? This hints of some fundamental flaws in the program design.

> extern

You should never need to use global variables in the C language (perhaps with the exception of MCU hardware peripheral registers). I haven't used global variables in the past 10 years and I work almost exclusively with embedded realtime systems. Again, this suggests that something is wrong in the program design.

> ...it saves the overhead of a function call. (this is for embedded stuff, so a function call is 'expensive-ish').

No it isn't. The C language has supported function inlining for 13 years, and even if you have an old C90 compiler, I bet it has an inlining option, `#pragma inline` or some such. I have yet to see an embedded compiler which lacks inlining. On top of that, even old compilers are fairly competent at performing inlining without any explicit hints from the programmer, if you only enable optimizations.

Also, is the function call overhead a bottleneck in the program, which you have found through benchmarking/measurements with an oscilloscope? If not, then why are you obfuscating your code with global variables and strange pointers that expose private data? That is premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

It is not encapsulation unless you have the ability to inject code between where the "user" of the structure reads it and where the data lies.  Such a shim allows you to change the internals of the structure without changing the external use of the structure.

While your solution is an improvement on the way things are typically done in C, to encapsulate it, you would need to be able to change a field from a single value to a constructed value without changing any "external" code to prove that it is really encapsulated.

In C this is typically performed by hiding the data behind void pointers, or using declared (but undefined) structs on the external portions of the encapsulated code.

blah.h

```
struct myStruct_t;
typedef struct myStruct_t myStruct;

extern myStruct * const ptrConstMyStruct;

// if you want a constructor, you need to declare the
// method here, because only blah.c will know the struct
// size with this solution.
myStruct * new_myStruct();

// methods
myStruct_setData(myStruct* obj, char c);
char myStruct_getData(myStruct* obj);
```

blah.c

```
#include "blah.h"

struct myStruct_t {
    unsigned char data;
    unsigned int intdata;
};

static myStruct thisIsMyModulesData;

// no need to make the struct const, just the pointer
// otherwise, we would have to break the const just to change
// data, which now will only be done within this file.
myStruct * const ptrConstMyStruct = &thisIsMyModulesData;
```

anotherFile.c

```
#include "blah.h"
// anotherFile "knows" of a struct called myStruct, but
// it doesn't know what it contains, or even it's size.

// this is no longer possible
// now "data" is encapsulated, and can be changed
// by reimplementing `myStruct_getData(...)`
// (as long as we don't change the method signature).
variable = ptrConstMyStruct->data;

// this is the "new" way
variable = myStruct_getData(ptrConstmyStruct);

// with the old, compiler error because of 
// assigning a value to a const value.
ptrConstMyStruct->data = variable; //compile error!
                       ^
              (error occurs here)

// with the new, compiler error because of
// dereferencing a pointer to a unknown / incomplete type.
ptrConstMyStruct->data = variable; // compile error!
                ^
        (error occurs here)
```

As you can see the location of the error makes the difference between encapsulation or not.  You can't change the relationship between the pointer and the data with `ptrConstMyStruct->data` if you check for errors at the assignment instead of the dereference.

Comment: This is commonly referred to as "opaque type". It is an object-orientation design similar to abstract base classes and heritage in other languages. But you shouldn't use global variables for this. Instead let the module where the type is defined allocate an instance of the opaque type through a function and return a pointer to that allocated instance to the caller. (Works pretty much in the same way as abstract base class pointers in C++)

Comment: Glad to know it has a name.  I didn't like the global variable either, but left it in since that's what he started with.